# allow attribute with some value but disallow all others

Tags: xslt

In my xslt I want to keep all class attributes that have class="myName" but remove all other class attributes on any node.

Could someone please help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any other templates matching elements with `@class`, this will work:

```
<xsl:template match="@class[.!='myName']"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved simply by overriding the identity transform, and adding a template to ignore the **class** attributes that don't have the correct value

So, given the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@class[. != 'myName']" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following XML

```
<a class="remove">
    <b class="myName">Test</b>
</a>
```

The following is output

```
<a>
    <b class="myName">Test</b>
</a>
```